# Is it possible to get the errno behind an IOException?

Tags: java, java-io

I’m working with sockets in Java, and when the socket is closed by the other side, I might get exceptions like:

```
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
```

In that case, I know the connection is broken (that’s `strerror(EPIPE)` and `strerror(ECONNRESET)`), and I should do something about that. Other errors might have other meanings, and I might be able to continue using the socket without problems.

But if I run Java under another locale, the error might turn into:

```
java.io.IOException: Datenübergabe unterbrochen (broken pipe)
java.io.IOException: Die Verbindung wurde vom Kommunikationspartner zurückgesetzt
```

The first message still includes the English (C) message, so I can match on that, but the second doesn’t. Is there any way to find out what the errno behind this exception is, other than shipping a reverse `strerror` catalogue for all locales with my library?

Comment: Just a question, is it possible to work around by setting the default `Locale` to English? Then you'd hold your actual locale in another variable? This would force you to pass the locale around and use it everywhere you usually don't.

Comment: Setting `LC_MESSAGES` to `C` works, so I think I’ll recommend that to library users. Not sure if setting the Java locale would have an effect here.

Answer (score -1):

Normally you won't get error numbers from `java.io.IOException`.

The reason for this is that there are no error numbers consistent across all platforms Java runs on.

Comment: 'Normally'? You will *never* get `errno` values from `java.io.IOException`. The reason is that there is no API provided for it.

Comment: 'Never' isn't true. Even Java's standard library sometimes includes error numbers from the OS in `java.io.IOException` error messages.

Comment: Please provide an example to support your claim.

Comment: Run e.g. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("foo");` or see the widely used `NET_ThrowByNameWithLastError` function http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/windows/native/java/net/net_util_md.c

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to know. The only `IOException` you need to distinguish even slightly is `SocketTimeoutException`. All others, and arguably that one as well, and *especially* the two you mention, are fatal to the connection, so the only reasonable thing to do is close the socket and forget about the peer.

Comment: While I agree on the general premise, there are some IOException that are perfectly reasonable to distinguish, such as `CharacterEncodingException` (in case where you're trying to discover it).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire The question however is about sockets closed by the peer, or dropped connections.

Comment: @EJP The question, as asked in the headline and in the text, is about getting the error number behind an `IOException`.

Comment: I guess this answers my problem – if there are no non-fatal `IOException`s (I only read/write byte buffers, so no `CharacterEncodingException`), then I can just treat them all equally. Thanks.

Comment: @LucasWerkmeister I can only suggest you re-read my answer. I have not stated anywhere that there are 'no non-fatal `IOException`s'. In fact I stated the exact opposite.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, every one of these IOExceptons is an instance of another, meaning you can just peerform `instanceof` checks, or use getClass() to resolve the error name.
For example a failed bind is an instance of `BindException`

Comment: But then wouldn’t I see `java.io.BindException: <message>` in the stack trace instead of `java.io.IOException`?

Comment: What is your source? I don't see any `Bind<Something>Exception` in [the list of subclasses of `IOException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html).

Comment: Well, this class is in its hierarchy under SocketException, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/BindException.html

Comment: @ArsenArsen Okay, my mistake. But what about `Broken pipe` and `Connection reset by peer` which are the errors asked in the original question?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I am still trying to find the library that throws these exceptions, or the import names.

Comment: This answer is simply incorrect. `IOException: connection reset by peer` and `IOException: broken pipe`, the ones mentioned in the question, are not instances of subclasses and cannot be distinguished by `instanceof`.